# How to know if rule is failing in vuetify's v-text-field?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

How do I know if a "rule" is failing in vuetify? I have a text field

```
<v-text-field label="Friendly URL" :rules="[rules.friendlyUrl]" v-model="friendlyUrl"></v-text-field>
```

And my rules definition:

```
data () {
  return {
    rules:{
      friendlyUrl(value){
        console.log('validating value');
        if (/^[a-z0-9\-]*$/.test(value)){
          return true;
        }
        return 'only lowercase letters, numbers and dashes are allowed'
      }
    }
  }
```

I want to "watch" something to know if my rule has failed or not. That way I can disable a submit button until all rules have passed.

Bonus points if you know how to set this up for multiple text fields.

Comment: This all comes out of the box with Vuetify. https://vuetifyjs.com/components/forms  https://codepen.io/pen/?editors=1010

Comment: Aah, I see, I need to wrap it in a v-form! Tons of searching and I couldn't find this :-(. Feel free to add that as an official answer and I'll mark it as accepted!

Comment: Thank you so much for this!! I've been searching for this for about 2 days now!!!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Vuetify will do this for you if you use their [`v-form` component](https://vuetifyjs.com/components/forms).

```
<v-form v-model="valid">
  <v-text-field label="Friendly URL" :rules="[rules.friendlyUrl]" v-model="friendlyUrl"></v-text-field>
</v-form>
```

Where, `valid` is a boolean data property. You can use it to toggle buttons, set classes, etc.

Comment: The pen example seems no longer valid.

Comment: @Ifty Thanks, I removed it. I think I just pasted the wrong link when I originally answered.

Comment: what about when having multiple inputs? it won't work in that case

Answer (score 0):

You can create any validators like this:

```
    const friendURLValidator = (value)=>{
        if (/^[a-z0-9\-]*$/.test(value)){
          return true;
        }
        return 'only lowercase letters, numbers and dashes are allowed'
   }
```

And define your custom validators inside of attribute :rules as follows:

```
  <VTextField :rules=[friendURLValidator]></VTextField>
```